# Docker Python App with Flet: Stuck on "Reconnecting"

Tags: python, docker, flet

I'm trying to deploy a flet app in a docker container. The problem is, on my windows machine the docker container works fine and the app runs perfectly.

But on the docker container on my Synology NAS, when I try to run the app, it gets stuck on "Please wait, the app is re-connecting"

Here is the Dockerfile I'm using

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /ime_interface

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./ime_interface_web/main.py"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

[Settings on my Synology NAS docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP9aI.png)

[Settings for volume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geBDK.png)

I tred to SSH into the container and look for the problem, but it's the exact same container as my windows machine one, and I can't seem the find the issue.